# Is there an Eclipse plugin for WSYIWYG UI for Android

Tags: android

I'm just starting out working with Android and it was recommended to me to try and find an Eclipse WYSIWYG plugin that could handle the top layer UI.

So far my searches haven't come up with much other than App Inventor (which won't really do the trick).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Mt

Answer (score 4):

In eclipse, you can get a WYSIWYG editor for the xml layout files. It can be found in the tab called "Graphical Layout" when you have a layout xml file open.

For example, if you create a new project, in the layout folder there is the main.xml file which automatically created. If you open this file, you should see two tabs at the bottom left of the editor. One which says "Graphical Layout" and another which says "main.xml". Open the Graphical Layout tab and it's as close to a WYSIWYG editor as I've found.

This is natively supported by the android sdk.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to suggest the UI designer built into ADT as well...but honestly its pretty weak.  I just saw the latest android dev blog entry about Android 3.0 (Honeycomb).  Apparently they made some major improvements to the UI Designer :]

Answer (score 2):

Try DroidDraw

http://www.droiddraw.org/

Comment: Very cool - So dumb question, when I'm done creating my layout can I import this into eclipse and write the underlying functionality?